# How to use Quarkus for multi provider OIDC?

Tags: openid-connect, quarkus

I would like to use OIDC in a Quarkus application for authentication and identification of the users. The user should be able to choose between different providers ("Login with Google", "Login with Facebook", ...). I managed the setup with a single provider, but how do I have to approach for the multi-provider solution?

Comment: Would you be ok with something like Keycloak or AWS Cognito in front of Quarkus?

Answer (score 2):

Sure, please follow [Quarkus OIDC MultiTenancy](https://quarkus.io/guides/security-openid-connect-multitenancy) guide. Create a configuration per every required provider (tenant) - either in `application.properties` and resolve it with custom `TenantResolver` or dynamically with `TenantConfigResolver`.
Typically, unauthenticated users would go, for example, to `/login/facebook`, so the resolver would check the last path segment and find a matching configuration. If the user is already authenticated, the tenant id will be made available as a `RoutingContext` `tenant-id` attribute. So the resolver should check the attribute first - if it is available - return it, if not - it means it is a new user request - check the path segment now.
See also: https://quarkus.io/guides/security-openid-connect-providers
HTH

Comment: Interposing with a single provider as suggested by @stdunbar can also be a viable alternative as it can help with managing things like global logout etc - but the multi-tenancy configuration concept still applies - it would be about configuring for example multiple Keycloak realms instead